# Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run. is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a code associated with a Google Spreadsheet, accessible via the script editor. In the code, I have a `.gs` file as the main body and I have an HTML file which is a sidebar used in the spreadsheet. I'm trying to call a function in the `sheet.gs` file from the HTML editor, would I do this using `google.script.run.myFunction()` in the HTML File, am I doing this wrong?

Basically in my sheet.gs I have

```
function myFunction() {
    // do a thing
}
```

and in my HTML file I'm trying to call `myFunction()` like `google.script.run.myFunction()`.

---

I have this function that is called by a button click

```html
<div class="btn" onclick="generateSpreadsheetReport()">View Responses</div>
```

and the function is

```
function generateSpreadsheetReport() {
console.log("RUN!");
console.log("StudentAverage1");
var day = document.getElementById("day");
if (!day.value) day.value = "";
var course = document.getElementById("courses");
var stud = document.getElementById("stud");
console.log(day.value,course.value,stud.value)
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayAverage).sortByParameter(day.value||"", course.value||"", stud.value||"");
console.log("StudentAverage2");
google.script.run.getStudentAverage(); // <----- This line right here isn't working.
}
```

And then in my sheet.gs I have a function called `getStudentAverage()` which is defined and it shows up in the library when I click on it from the resources page. So I Assume I am calling it wrong in my HTML

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, but from the looks of it in your `sheet.gs` try changing your

```
myFunction() {
    // do a thing
}
```

to

```
function myFunction() {
    return true;
}
```

It's just a wild guess based on the problem you've explained. Try this and let us know if it works for you.

**Update:** from your HTML file invoke `myFunction()` like

```
function myFunction() {
        return true;
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(myparam){
   console.log("Response: "+myparam);
}).myFunction();
```

Comment: Sorry, In my actual code, I have function myFunction() {

} 

I'll update my question.

Comment: Follow how you implement `sortByParameter()`, set `google.script.run.getStudentAverage();` to `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getStudentAverage();`. See the documentation - [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) for code implementation and guide. Hope this helps.